How to add 3rd party htmls to sphinx index.rst content?
I am working on documenting a project in C++.
The workflow is set as follows: I write my documentation in .h files. The headers are then loaded into Doxygen and html files are generated. These files are then loaded into sphinx and final htmls are generated. I have set Doxyfile and conf.py (for Sphinx) so that I can achieve the result automatically by simple calling make html.
As a result, I get a bunch of htmls (by doxygen) in my build folder as well as index.rst (by Sphinx). The latter is empty. I want to populate it with files from doxygen.
Setting html_extra_path to be the path where doxygen htmls files are stores seems a legit way according to the Sphinx documentation. However, to add files to index.rst, paths relative to source dir must be typed, which I can't achieve as htmls are in build dir and not source.
Moreover, when I simply copy an html to the source dir and type its name in index.rst I get the "File does not exist" error when I call make html
My conf.py:
import subprocess

project = 'TestDocumentation'
copyright = '2024, Nikita'
author = 'Nikita'

extensions = [
#    'sphinx.ext.autodoc'
]

templates_path = ['_templates']
exclude_patterns = []

html_theme = 'alabaster'
html_static_path = ['_static']

subprocess.call('make clean', shell=True)
subprocess.call('doxygen ../Doxyfile', shell=True)
html_extra_path = ['doxygen/html']

My index.rst
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

   files

("files" is a name of a file from doxygen).
I would like to get here a brief walkthrough on how to integrate pre-generated htmls in my Sphinx project. Thank you.
P.S. I would also be grateful if anyone could explain to me the need for Sphinx in this scheme. It was set before I got this assignment so I would like to comprehend all ins and outs. Although, doxygen itself is capable of producing htmls, as far as I get, Sphinx is needed for visuals and more control over documentation structure.

I now get that the problem is that you add other .rst files into index.rst, and not htmls, which I get from doxygen. So how could I add my doxygen-generated htmls though....?
